# Tests do not execute on Spring 2.6.X

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

My junit tests worked fine on 2.5.3 until I upgraded to the 2.6.X version.
Now I'm getting this error on every class used in the tests:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXXXXX

Test dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using mongo embedded for testing:

`spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.3.5`

Tests are basic `@SpringBootTest` with `@Test` annotation

EDIT:

I saw the issue is the mongodb version `spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.4.13`

It's trying to get the mongo from a bad url:

Could not open inputStream for https://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-4.4.13.zip

It should be -> https://fastdl.mongodb.org/windows/mongodb-windows-x86_64-4.4.13.zip

What is happening?